# Connect ELM327 (WiFi interface) OBD-II scanner to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-2

I have recently purchased an OBD-II scanner, ELM327 Wifi Interface, which I need to connect to my Raspberry Pi over Wifi. Which libraries do I need to import to get data from OBD-II scanner to my RPi? Is there any available software (as Scanmaster, in case of Windows) on Raspbian OS to get this working directly?